# Cypress code coverage not running against all files

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, code-coverage, cypress-code-coverage

We've recently implemented Cypress tests, and I'm trying to set up code coverage reports to ensure we can track coverage of new code. I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage), however when I run my cypress tests the only file showing as tested in my report is `cypress/support/e2e.js`, rather than the actual files in my repo.

My folder structure for my repo is as follows:

```
|/src
| /api
   /tennis
    /player.js
     ... 
|/cypress
| /e2e
   /tennis
    /player.cy.js
     ...
| /support
   /e2e.js
|/coverage
| /lcov-report
   /index.html
     ...
```

And we've added the following cypress.config.js:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.js',
    screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
    video: false,
    reporter: "cypress-multi-reporters",
    reporterOptions: {
      configFile: "./cypress/cypress-reporters.json"
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
      on('file:preprocessor', require('@cypress/code-coverage/use-babelrc'))
      return config
    },
  }
})
```

My `cypress/support/e2e.js` file has the following:

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

And my .babelrc file imports "istanbul" for instrumentation.

When I run my cypress tests, I can see the logs for the expected before / afterEach / after functions associated with cypress tests, and I've attached an image of what `console.log(window.__coverage__`) displays: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCBEQ.jpg)

At the end of my tests, however, `.nyc_output/out.json` is an empty object, and the html coverage report just shows [coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esasN.png)

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong with my setup to display the full cypress coverage reports? Please let me know if you need any info in addition to the above.

Thanks in advance